# listbox isSelected databinding in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls, datatemplate

I try to simply databind `IsSelected` property with `IsSelected` field in my class. But after I change the value in code, it doesn't change the property, neither does clicking on `ListBoxItem` change the field value.

XAML:

```
<FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}" ... >
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" 
                Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates">
                <!-- other controls -->
                <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    SelectionMode="Multiple" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}">
                    <ListBox.Resources>
                        <local:LogicToText x:Key="logToText" />
                    </ListBox.Resources>

                     <!-- bind IsSelected only in one way from 
                         code to content --> 
                     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListBoxItem 
                              IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource logToText}}" 
                              Content="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource logToText}}">

                            </ListBoxItem>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>


                    <!-- not working at all
                    <ListBox.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" 
                                Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Content" 
                                Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.Resources>-->

                </ListBox>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Code:

Answers

```
private ObservableCollection<PrawoJazdyDataAnswer> _answers = 
    new ObservableCollection<PrawoJazdyDataAnswer>();
public ObservableCollection<PrawoJazdyDataAnswer> Answers 
{ 
    get 
    { 
       return this._answers; 
    }  
}
```

Single item(Answer)

```
public class PrawoJazdyDataAnswer : NPCHelper// PrawoJazdy.Common.BindableBase
{
    public PrawoJazdyDataAnswer(String ans, bool ansb)
    {
        this._ans = ans;
        this._isSelected = ansb;
    }

    public override string ToString() 
    { 
        return _isSelected.ToString();  //Only For debug purposes 
                                        //normally return _ans 
    }
    private string _ans;
    public string Ans
    {
        get { return this._ans; }
        //set { this.SetProperty(ref this._ans, value); }
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return this._isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            //this.SetProperty(ref this._isSelected, value); 
        }
    }
}
```

FirePropertyChanged

```
public class NPCHelper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void FirePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Converter(which sometimes seems to be needed and others not..., I tried ~10 approaches from different tutorials/examples)

```
public class LogicToText : IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, string language)
    {
        //if (value == null || (bool)value == false)
          //  return "False";

        return value.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value.ToString().Contains("True") ? true : false;
    }
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my English(still learning).

@edit
Thanks for quick reply.

For test purposes I created a button and text block:

```
<Button Click="spr" >Sprawdź</Button>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Answers[0].IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" > </TextBlock>
```

It's in other controls part (above list box, but in `FlipView`)
Click method

```
private void spr(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ans = ((PrawoJazdyDataQuestion)this.flipView.SelectedItem).Answers;
        foreach (var item in ans)
            item.IsSelected = item.IsSelected ? false : true;
    }
```

As I wrote, when i'm changing data from code side, it is changing content of element, but not appearance of `ListBoxItem`. And if I just select it on `ListBox`, it doesn't change the data in `TextBlock` neither in `ListBox` itself.

@edit2 fixing typos...

Comment: The converter shouldn't be needed since the binding source and target properties are both type `bool`. Everything looks good to me though. Can you post some sample code of how you are updating the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not bind to IsSelected on ListBoxItem. ListBox got SelectedItem or SelectedItems property, where You should pass item(s) to be selected, i.e. by binding.
Setting IsSelected property in model is not good idea. Better make SelectedItem notify property in ViewModel.

Answer (score 11):

To change the `IsSelected` property of the `ListBoxItem`, you need to change the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`. See here:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                SelectionMode="Multiple" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Since the binding mode is `TwoWay`, selecting and deselecting the `ListBoxItem`'s dynamically changes the content of the items to display either `True` or `False`.

Also notice how I changed the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` into a `TextBlock` instead of a `ListBoxItem`. The `ItemTemplate` defines the content of the `ListBoxItem`, so some type of content control is typically used. Below is the UI structure for the different layouts (this can be viewed using the WPF Tree Visualizer).

`ListBoxItem` as the `ItemTemplate`:

[image]

`TextBlock` as the `ItemTemplate`:

[image]

**Edit**

Also note that I removed the `IValueConverter`. Since your source and target properties are both `bool`, there is no need for a converter in this case. Try removing the converter references to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply but after code change it's still working in a way it's used to, text is changing but selection doesn't appear.

Comment: @Kinmarui Alright. I meant set the breakpoint in your code behind on the `IsSelected` property setter of the `PrawoJazdyDataAnswer` class. That setter should be fired when you select/deselect a list item if the binding is set up correctly.

Comment: if you meant 
`public bool IsSelected { set {_isSelected = value;} }`
then it isn't fired up when I click on item in ListBox, only when I click button.

Comment: @Kinmarui That setter should have fired. For some reason the binding is not working. You can looking in the output window for binding errors (if you don't see any you might need to set this option **Tools->Options->Debugging->Output Window->WPF Trace Settings->Data Binding** to `Warning`). Also, [here](http://pastebin.com/8UiBhAma) is all my code for the test project I created which works

Comment: @MeadorDylan  
There are no errors or warnigs.
Thanks a lot for trying to help me,  
only thing now i can think is why its not working because of `listBox` is in `DataTemplate`, and in your example it's not. Now I try walk around this by binding `SelectedItems` property with another collection in codebehind.

Comment: @Kinmarui Yeah, sorry I couldn't find a solution. I'm not sure what's happening. It's interesting that there are no binding messages in the output window and the setter isn't being fired for that property.